# Python: "or" in short form

Tags: python

Is there a possibility to write this in a shorter way?

```
elif line.startswith('\tVLRLIST=') and (line.rstrip()[9:-1] == '27' or line.rstrip()[9:-1] == '28' or line.rstrip()[9:-1] == '29')
```

Comment: Please add a sample input and expected output. And properly format the code

Comment: `elif line.startswith('\tVLRLIST=') and (line.rstrip()[9:-1] in ('27', '28', '29')` or `elif line.startswith('\tVLRLIST=') and (line.rstrip()[9:-1] in map(str, range(27, 30))`

Answer (score 3):

As a general case, you can use the `in` keyword,

```
elif line.startswith('\tVLRLIST=') and line.rstrip()[9:-1] in ('27', '28', '29'):
```

For this specific example, all of them are contained in a range:

```
elif line.startswith('\tVLRLIST=') and (int(line.rstrip()[9:-1]) in range(27, 30):
```

Answer (score 3):

```
elif re.match(r'^\tVLRLIST=2[7-9]\s*$', line):
```

Comment: upvoted because it nicely answers the particular case of the OP, but it does not really answer the general question of 'Python: "or" in short form'

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach and try to name these, it's much more readable.

```
def prefix_is_correct(line):
    return line.startswith('\tVLRLIST=')

def is_valid(line):
    return prefix_is_correct(line) and line.rstrip()[9:-1] is in ['27', '28', '29']

.
.
.

elif is_valid(line):
```